# how to set time out on js onlick method in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a search bar with search function using javascript. onclick it will drop down some results . But i need to set an time 1 min to show the dropdown result, aslo can function the search propriety as old.

> HTML CODE

```
<div class="dropdown">
   <input onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn" id="myInput" 
   placeholder="Search Stores & Brands" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search form-control-feedback"></span>

  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">    
     <a href="<?php echo site_url()?>welcome/search_Bonanza">Bonanza</a>
     <a href="<?php echo site_url()?>welcome/search_BestBuy">BestBuy</a>
     <a href="<?php echo site_url()?>welcome/search_Belk">Belk</a>
     <a href="<?php echo site_url()?>welcome/search_Benmeadows">Benmeadows</a>
     <a href="<?php echo site_url()?>welcome/search_Backcountry">Backcountry</a>
     <a href="<?php echo site_url()?>welcome/search_Cosme_de">Cosme - de</a>
```

> JS CODE

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}
function filterFunction() {
   var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
   input = document.getElementById("myInput");
   filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
   div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
   a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
   for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
       if (a[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
           a[i].style.display = "";
       } else {
           a[i].style.display = "none";
       }
    }
}
```

- i need ony 1 or 2 min to active the onclick method and remove and other felter function remain same

Comment: setTimeout(function(){/*code goes here */},1000 /*time in ms*/)

Comment: `setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById("myInput").onclick = null; document.getElementById("myInput").onkeyup = null; }, 60000);` will remove the event handlers from the input after 1 minute. Is that what you meant?

Comment: no it's not.i need to perform the onclick function show results for 1 min .

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that then. You want to automate the "click" action?

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle again the class list :

```
function myFunction() {
     document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
     setTimeout(function(){
                  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
     },60000);//60000 for 1 minute.
    }
```

Comment: Hope this one gave you the desired output.